# how to print selected column in datagridview in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview

how to print selected column in datagridview in vb.net?
coz I want to print the selected rows in vb.net, the rows have true visibility.
this is my code in "PrintDocument1_PrintPage",

```
With DataGridView1
    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)

    fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter

    Dim y As Single = 190
    Do While mRow < .RowCount
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
        Dim x As Single = 50
        Dim h As Single = 0
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells


            Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)

            e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)

            x += rc.Width
            h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)

        Next
        newpage = False
        y += h
        mRow += 1
        If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
            e.HasMorePages = True
            mRow -= 1
            newpage = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop
    mRow = 0

End With
```

-my problem is, it prints all the rows in my datagridview even if it have false visibility.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking to see if the row is Visible or not.  As you may know, programming languages can interact with non-visible objects, so just because it is not visible does not mean your code will not see it.

You can probably just put a conditional within your Do While loop...

```
Do WHile mRow < .RowCount
Dim row as DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
    If row.Visible then
        'blah blah blah
    EndIf
Loop
```